# Is there an example of universal approximators whose value at the origin is fixed as zero?

Tags: approximation-theory

I'd like to know whether there is an example of universal approximators whose value at the origin is fixed as zero.

### Motivation

Let's think about $C_{0} := \{f:X \to \mathbb{R}| f \text{is continuous}, f(0)=0\}$, where $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set.
One may use a universal approximator $\hat{f}$ (e.g., feedforward neural network) to approximate any function $f$ in $C_{0}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ so that
$$
\lVert \hat{f} - f \rVert_{\infty} < \epsilon.
$$
But one cannot guarantee that $\hat{f}(0) = 0$.

### Question

Given $f \in C_0$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, is there any universal approximator $\hat{f}_{0}$ such that $\lVert \hat{f}_0 - f\rVert_{\infty} <\epsilon$ and $\hat{f}_0(0) = 0$?

### Notes

EDIT: I'd like to know the name of $C_{0}$ or such universal approximator $\hat{f}_0$ if it exists.

Comment: If you know that $\lVert \hat{f}_0 - f\rVert_{\infty} <\epsilon$ then just subtract from $\hat{f}_0$ its value at $0$ to get approximation which is $2\epsilon$ from $f$

Comment: @Salcio Umm... actually my problem is more complicated than that. I'd like to keep its value at the origin is zero "while training". I also considered your way, but it's a kind of manipulation "after training", so it seems not a possible solution in this case.

Comment: @Salcio After a while, I realised that your suggestion makes sense and may be able to be used for practical use. Thanks